# Writing an iOS 8 share extension without a storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, ios-app-extension

Does anyone know of a good way to write an iOS 8 share extension without the `MainInterface.storyboard` that comes with the template?

When I delete the file or remove the `NSExtensionMainStoryboard` from `Info.plist`, the extension stops working (nothing happens when you tap on the button in the share pane). We tried replacing `NSExtensionMainStoryboard` with `NSExtensionPrincipalClass` which also didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Figured it out!

Turns out there's a weird module naming thing going on in Swift, so you can fix it by adding an `@objc` name to the class:

```
@objc(PrincipalClassName)

class PrincipalClassName: UIViewController {
...
```

and then set the `NSExtensionPrincipalClass` key to `PrincipalClassName`.

Comment: Hey! Thanks, can you specify the source of where you found this?

Comment: When using Swift, you need to specify 'NotificationContent.NotificationContentViewController` in your Info.plist's `NSExtensionPrincipalClass` key's value field. In here, `NotificationContent` is module name, and `NotificationContentViewController` is the only view controller class.

Answer (score 26):

Instead of the `@objc` hack, the proper way to do it in Swift is to include the module name in `NSExtensionPrincipalClass`, i.e.,

```xml
<key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).ActionViewController</string>
```

(Documenting the error otherwise:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]: object cannot be nil (key: ...)'
```

Hopefully will help someone who run into this error in the future.)

Xcode 15 shows an error that is verbose and more helpful:

```
__extensionPrincipalClass != nil - /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/ExtensionFoundation_Sim/ExtensionFoundation/Source/NSExtension/NSExtensionSupport/EXConcreteExtensionContextVendor.m:109:
Unable to find NSExtensionPrincipalClass (MessagesViewController) in
extension bundle! Please verify that the extension links the required
frameworks and that the value for NSExtensionPrincipalClass is
prefixed with '$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).' if the class is implemented in
Swift. Type: Fault | Timestamp: 2023-09-19 18:05:10.722854-07:00 |
Library: ExtensionFoundation | Subsystem: com.apple.extensionkit |
Category: default | TID: 0x4f172
```

Comment: I agree this is a better solution than the @objc directive, and also more clear. Worked for me 

Comment: Glory to you! Been looking for the reason why my code was crashing and would not have figured that one out on my own 

Answer (score 15):

Found the answers from these answers combined [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25384115/1565971) and [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26847727/1565971).

For Objective-C you will have to put the following in the `info.plist` of the App extension:
`NSExtensionPrincipalClass` and make sure that it is under `NSExtension` Dict

So full answer should be like this , in my case `ActionViewController` is the App extension viewController

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Can't add a comment but it is no longer **NSPrincipalClass** rather it is **NSExtensionPrincipalClass**