# How to create a Today widget programmatically without storyboard on iOS8?

Tags: ios, widget, ios8, ios-app-extension

I tried to delete the storyboard file and related `Info.plist` entry but this time extension stopped working; it doesn't even launch from XCode.

`The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)`

It is easy on the regular app (containing app) as we see it's entry point and application delegate, but how to do it on extensions too?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Remove `NSExtensionMainStoryboard` from `Info.plist`
Add `NSExtensionPrincipalClass = YourViewController`

Don't forget to create your own view in `loadView`

Comment: Note: This needs to be under the NSExtension dictionary in the info.plist for the extension.

Comment: had to do this to make it work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416003/writing-an-ios-8-share-extension-without-a-storyboard

Comment: Yeah this post works, you have to insert `@objc(PrincipalClassName)` before your main class declaration

Answer (score 47):

I did the following steps:

- Delete the storyboard file from your project
- Modify the info.plist:

Go to the NSExtension Dictionary, remove this key: NSExtensionMainStoryboard. Replace it with this key NSExtensionPrincipalClass and add your ViewController as the value, e.g. TodayViewController.

before:

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
    <string>MainInterface</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.widget-extension</string>
</dict>
```

after:

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>TodayViewController</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.widget-extension</string>
</dict>
```

- If you're using Swift, you have to enable "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code" in the Build Settings of the target. Set it to YES.
- Additionally I had to add `@objc (TodayViewController)` in my TodayViewController class (after the imports).

The app should run now. But there were two other things I had to do:

- Create a view. Obviously there is no view created automatically.

So add these lines:

```
override func loadView()
{
    view = UIView(frame:CGRect(x:0.0, y:0, width:320.0, height:200.0))
}
```

- And set the height of your widget in your viewDidLoad method: `self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 200)`

Comment: had to do this to make it work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416003/writing-an-ios-8-share-extension-without-a-storyboard

Comment: May I ask why we have to create a view in the TodayViewController class? Isn't the View Controller already contains a view already?

Comment: @Raphael, nice answer. I wanted to follow a similar logic for an iMessage extension, but wasn't able to. :-/

Comment: @Raphael, actually I did. Not sure if this is an efficient way. (By adding a childViewController.) But, I guess the crash that resulted in the morning, was to a typo!! :-(

Answer (score 8):

FWIW, it didn't work for me until I added a prefix of the module name for my Swift view controller class, e.g.

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <!-- ... -->
    <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>SafariActionExtension.RootViewController</string>
    <!-- ... -->
</dict>
```

That is probably because class lookup for Swift modules turns module names into prefix for class name. E.g. to create your class in code you would write `NSStringFromClass("SafariActionExtension.RootViewController")`, hence the prefix.

Comment: I couldn't get it working with the prefix, so I just used the @obj(RootViewController) to specify the class name and it works.

Comment: This answer solved my problem! :-) Should be marked as right answer!