# Is it possible to open full view controller in Share extension, instead of popup (default)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, ios8-share-extension

I am working on `Share extension` & I have one query related to this.

Is it possible to open full view controller in Share extension, also can we add `UITableView` or other `IBoutlet` using `Storyboard` in `Share extension`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, whatsapp does that.

Comment: Check this out, this is old version of swift but you can take help from it. https://github.com/martinnormark/ShareByMail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Step1:*** Add new `UIViewController` named `MainPageViewController`.

***Step2:*** Add new View Controller in `MainInterface` Storyboard, change it's class to  `MainPageViewController` in Custom Class section of Storyboard, set `Storyboard ID` to `MainPageViewController` in Identity section.

***Step3:***  Open Share extension's info.plist

By default it looks something like this-

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <string>TRUEPREDICATE</string>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
        <string>MainInterface</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    </dict>
```

Now instead of the default `NSExtensionMainStoryboard` key use `NSExtensionPrincipalClass` key, so the final result will be

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <string>TRUEPREDICATE</string>
        </dict>
            <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
            <string>HomeViewController</string>
            <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
        </dict>
```

Where `HomeViewController` is our new entry point controller.

***Step4:*** Now, the **most important** we need to [fix weird issue related with module naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416003/writing-an-ios-8-share-extension-without-a-storyboard/24416403#24416403).

To fix it we need to add `@objc(HomeViewController)` at the top of your `HomeViewController` file.

***Step5:*** Also to animate the presentation, we need to add animation code in `viewWillAppear`

> See below reference code:

```
import UIKit

@objc(HomeViewController)

class HomeViewController : UINavigationController {

     init() {
        let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "MainInterface", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainPageViewController") as UIViewController
        super.init(rootViewController: viewController)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        })
    }
}
```

Where `MainPageViewController` is the identifier of your `MainViewController`, which we want to present.

***Step6:*** To dismiss with animation we can create new function in `MainPageViewController` class:

```
func hideExtensionWithCompletionHandler(completion:@escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.20, animations: {

        self.navigationController!.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.navigationController!.view.frame.size.height)
    }, completion: completion)
}
```

call above func on Save or Cancel button and inside block, we can call `completeRequest` or `cancelRequest(withError:)`

```
func saveButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.hideExtensionWithCompletionHandler(completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
            self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: nil, completionHandler: nil)
        })
    }
```

Now, Do whatever you want to do man, Do double man ;-)